# Getting an unknown runtime error with IE javascript dealing with a textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, runtime-error

So Ive been working on this error for a while now, and I cant figure it out for the life of me. There are a couple questions on stackoverflow about this, but they dont pertain to me, at least I dont think so. I am pretty new to the programming world. But this is my situation.

The following code writes text in a textbox with setTimeout.

```
putftp.onclick = function () {

    var Text = document.getElementById("TextBox");
    function firsttext() {
        Text.innerHTML += "This is the first test.";
        setTimeout(secondtest, 3000);
    }
    function secondtest() {
        Text.innerHTML += "<br/>This is the second test.";
        //setTimeout(thirdtest, 5000);
    }
    firsttext();
};
```

My main goal was to start a new line (with the br), but for some reason, IE throws a fit and says its an unknown runtime error. Note that the code works perfect without the br but I would like for the "This is the second test." To start on a new line. Ive tried alot of things to fix this such as putting a div around the textbox, looking for stray br s in the code, and even getting rid of the textbox and just having a div works. But for some reason a textbox and the br arent working out together. Im using IE to test in and asp.net.

Anyone know the answer to this? Thanks for your help in advance!!

**Update** 
 \n works, but does not begin the text at a new line.
 
 gives the same result at

Comment: Have you tried using "\n" as a newline character? I suspect the issue is due to putting HTML into the textbox - usually you'd just use string formatting instead.

Comment: I have tried that and no luck. Actually let me rephrase, the \n does work. But it does not start at a new line.

Comment: Put in a `debugger;` breakpoint, open your favorite javascript console and type `Text.innerHTML` What does it say?  I really suggest moving to a standard library for this sort of thing, like jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out but thanks to all who tried.

I ended up using \n with the original textbox   and changed Text.innerHTML to Text.innerTEXT

Comment: Did you try Text.value as recommended in my answer?  Just curious to see if that worked for you too.  In my testing, it was the most consistent when working with IE.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try `<br />` Notice the space after the r and before the slash.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to setTimeout is a string:

```
setTimeout('secondtest()', 3000);
```

Comment: what exactly are you saying? Im pretty new to javascript.

Comment: the correct syntax for the call to setTimeout is to pass the text of the command to execute when the timer expires, so it must be passed as a string. And I have edited my answer, because I did it wrong.

Comment: Actually, the first argument to setTimeout *can* be a string, but it can also be a function handle.  e.g. `setTimeout(someFunc, 3000);`  Passing a string is generally considered bad practice, as it involves evoking eval().

Answer (score 0):

Use `Text.value` instead of `Text.innerHTML`.  IE doesn't like the innerHTML property when trying to insert a new line (and definitely use `\n` instead of `<br />`).